# Clarification about the header-guards and header-file inclusion used in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, header

I know people recommend including header guards in header files, to prevent header files contents from being inserted by the pre-processor into the source-code files more than once.

But consider the following scenario:

Let's say I have the files `main.cpp` , `stuff.cpp`, and `commonheader.h`, with the `.h` file having its header guards.

If either `.cpp` files tries to include `commonheader.h` more than once, then the preprocessor
will stop that from happening, and after compiling to object code we get,

`main.o` containing the contents of commonheader.h **exactly once.**

`stuff.o` containing the contents of commonheader.h **exactly once.**

Note that the contents of commonheader, have been repeated across the files, but not within the same `.o` file.

So what happens during the linking step? Since the .o files are being fused into an exectuable
we will have to ensure for a **second time** that the contents of commonheader are not being repeated. Does the compiler take care of that? If not, wouldn't that be a problem when we are dealing with huge header files,  giving rise to code repetition across files and leading to large executable sizes.

If I am making some conceptual mistake anywhere in the question, please correct me.

Comment: You mean that each object file is getting a copy of `commonheader.h`?

Comment: Why? I thought, the preprocessing stage involved directly pasting the contents of the header files into the source files.

Comment: Yes, the #include macro copies the contents of that file, probably after running it through the preprocessor.

Comment: #include will copy the file contents exactly where this word is placing! +1 for @dutt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically your header file should not actually **define** any symbols, it should just **declare** them.  So commonheader.h would look like this (omitting the include guards):

```
void commonFunc1(void);
void commonFunc2(void);
```

In that case, there is no problem.  If you call `commonFunc1` in `main.cpp` and `stuff.cpp`, both `main.o` and `stuff.o` will know they want to link against a symbol called `commonFunc1` and the linker will try to find that symbol.  If the linker doesn't find the symbol, you get an undefined reference error.  The actual definition of `commonFunc1` needs to be in some cpp file.

If you really want to define functions in your header file, use `static` so that the linker does not see them.  So your commonheader.h could look like:

```
static void commonFunc1()
{
    /* ... do stuff ... */
}
```

In this case, the linker does not know about `commonFunc1` and no errors will occur.  This could increase the executable size though; you'll probably end up with two copies of the code for `commonFunc1`.

Comment: Hm...isn't "extern" unecessary for function prototypes/declarations?

Comment: So referring to your last sentence, is that why it is advised to place the function definition and function decalarations in separate files? What about templated code? All templated functions are defined in headers, and if such files are included indiscriminately, I am guessing that would give rise to code bloat , correct?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure.  The C++ standard template library is pretty popular and you would think that there are good solutions to avoid code bloat when using it.  Maybe it's OK because the compiler will only use the code paths that your object actually needs and it can optimize away all the others.

Comment: Correct, you can't seperate templated code and yes, including it all over the place can lead to bloat. But on the other hand including normal headers all over the place also lead to bloat. You should take general care to only include the stuff you need. Include as little as possible in the headers and use type declarations, include the actual types in the .cpp files.

Comment: @curiousexplorer: If a template is instantiated with the same arguments in several object files, then yes, the same code will be available in both. But the linker is usually smart enough to discard all the copies but one. You can try googling for "weak symbol" or something like that.

Comment: @rodrigo: ... which raises the question, why the linker is not smart enough to merge the other definitions :-P

Comment: @rodrigo Wait, so if I don't instantiate some templated-funciton included present in an included header file, does the compiler still compile that piece of code, or is it (or the linker) usually smart enough to discard thos templated functions which are not being used.

Comment: @curiousexplorer: Generally speaking, non instantiated templates generate no code at all. Templates are, after all, exactly that: templates to generate code. They are compiled, of course, but they generate code each time it is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

To expand Grayson's answer to cover variables. If you want to declare a variable in a header file you should use the extern keyword. This is one way to handle global variables.

In the header file global.h you write this:

```
extern Globals globals;
```

then you can use foo in any file including global.h, while in global.cpp you write

```
#include "globalstype.h"
Globals globals;
```

Note that global.cpp doesn't need to include global.h, however you will need to make sure global.cpp is compiled into each usage otherwise the linker will complain.

Comment: Yeah, this is important for variables because if you accidentally forget the `extern` keyword in your header file, you will probably end up with two different variables that have the same name.

Comment: In my experience(msvc, gcc) the linker will complain about multiple definitions if you actually get two usages/instances.

Answer (score 0):

Header files normally contain *declarative code* not *definitive code*.  That is they declare the existence of something that must exist exactly once.  Macros and inline functions are allowed and necessarily duplicate wherever they are used.

The declarations are used by the compiler to insert unresolved links (or references) into the object code.  The job of the linker is to resolve these links by matching the reference with the one single definition.

If you omit the include guards, with multiple inclusion in a *single translation unit* you will get a *compiler error* for multiple *declaration* of an existing symbol.  If however you have a header erroneously containing a definition, and the header is included in more than one translation unit, there will be more than one object file with a definition - this instead causes a *linker error* for multiple *definition*.

So while:

```
extern int b ;  // declaration, may occur in multiple translation units
```

is fin in a header file,

```
int b ; // definition, must occur in only object file.
```

is not.

Not the the declarations are not included in the object code, rather the compiler uses them to create references that the linker will resolve if the compiler has not already uses the definition and resolved it already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be a problem. You could end up with multiple definitions, or redundant copies.

C is quite simple in this regard. You have static, extern, and inline -- and compilers also define several ways to alter visibility. I think a lot of this has been covered by other answers.

C++ is quite different, however. There is a lot of information and there are also implicit definitions (e.g. the compiler may emit a copy constructor or RTTI).

With C++, the likelihood that a definition appears in a header is much more likely -- consider templates, methods defined in a class declaration, and so on. C++ defaults to using the One Definition Rule. You will want to read about it in more detail, but it basically states that some categories of symbols may be multiply-defined; depending on the decoration and the location/scope of declaration, that in many cases, the linker is allowed to assume that each body (definition) is identical and it is free to discard any copies it encounters (leaving one definition in your binary). So this really cuts down on the *size* of the resulting binary, unless you specify a copy shall be produced.

However, having those definitions in your headers can surely increase compilation times, memory and files required to compile each file, visible dependencies, and will increase the number of files which must be recompiled when a definition is edited.

Of course, the language still allows bad forms, and will not complain if you repeatedly state over and over again and include in multiple translations definitions which *must* be copied for each translation. Then you can certainly end up with a lot of bloat.

This may be a good intro:
http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=386

Comment: One question: If a templated function in a included-header file has not been used, is the compiler smart enough not to compile its contents and discard it completely?

Comment: @curiousexplorer yes -- to go even one step further, the template may never even be instantiated in that scenario. no definition would be created without instantiation (e.g. a specific use of the template, where the template parameters are defined). the program would need to be parsed, but no definitions would exist without instantiation.